# How to add new Row in DevExpress Gridview from DataTable on Button Click

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress

I am new to C# and trying to know more by trying to develop simple Windows application. In the application i used the DevExpress GridView. 
i am trying to add the content of textbox control to DevExpress Unbounded Gridview on button click like this. I tried like this but nothing show up in the GridView.

```
Private void btn_Add_to_List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        gridView1.AddNewRow();
    }

private void gridView1_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.InitNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view = sender as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView;
        view.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns[0], cBox_ProcessingMaterial.Text.ToString());
        view.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns[1], txtBox_Qty_Used.Text.ToString());


    }
```

[This is the form i used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I63Z5.png)

The version of DevExpress i am using is 16.2.4. i have seen the documentation but the only thing i get is for bounded GridView only. please i need help.
Thanks!!

Comment: What have you actually tried?  Does it work?  Not Work?  Give an error?

Answer (score 1):

When you call AddNewRow it will fire an event - InitNewRow. In there you can initialise the values of the new row.

This appears to be covered in their documentation: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_InitNewRowtopic

It includes an example, which is:

```
private void gridView1_InitNewRow(object sender, InitNewRowEventArgs e) {
   DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view = sender as Grid.GridView;
   view.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns["PurchaseDate"], DateTime.Today);
}
```